# Is there an effect size for a single proportion?

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

I want to conduct a meta analysis of the incidence rate of the complications of a specific disease.
Studies report these complications as 4 patients died or 2% died.
And there are no comparable group.Is it possible to have an effect size for single proportions.Any suggestions or further readings are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me take the title question ("Is there an effect size for a single proportion?") literally and set aside the meta analysis context.

There are effect sizes for single proportions, when a null proportion value is specified.  Moreover, the effect sizes for single proportions are the same as for two observed proportions and work the same way.  You could use:

1. The [difference of proportions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_risk_reduction): `prop - null`
2. The [ratio of proportions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_risk): `prop/null`
3. The [odds ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio): `[prop/(1-prop)]  /  [null/(1-null)]`

Returning to the context of meta analysis, you don't necessarily have to use these.  You might just be interested in estimating a proportion directly.  In which case, you wouldn't want to use these.  If there is a meaningful null and these studies compared the observed proportion to that, you could try using the log of the odds ratio.

Comment: 'when a null proportion value is specified.' can you tell me more about it? I only have the measured proportion e.g. 2% died. what's the null proportion then?

Comment: The idea is that there is some specific value that has a theoretical basis, & that you are trying to disprove. Eg, everyone believes that 4.5% die, & the point of these studies is to test that proposition. It isn't clear that that's the case in your situation. The other answers are probably more appropriate to your situation, @ahmedmar.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the command metaprop in the package meta of r. These type of studies are called incidence meta-analysis or single-proportion meta-analysis.

In this particular case the effect size would be the proportion of the variable studied and the meta analysis would compute a different weight and confidence interval according to the sample size.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be careful here. Do you really mean an incidence rate? By that I mean that people were followed for a period of time and then the number of events is reported as a rate per person year (or some either measure of time). If you do then I think you need something other than metaprop from meta. I assume you can use some other command in meta (with which I am not too familiar) but metafor (also available from CRAN) has several options for rates.